# envoy deploys: Problems running envoy run deploy command

Tags: linux, laravel, laravel-envoy

Envoy Version: 2.2.0

Laravel Version: 6.18.3

PHP Version: 7.4.8

Database Driver & Version: mysql 15.1 Distrib 10.3.23-MariaDB

I have deployed the Envoy package successfully at my Vagrant Homestead Laravel box and works like a charm. I implemented the Envoy.blade.php with all tasks and instructions to make deployments and it works pretty well. When I type in the terminal `envoy run deploy`, he deployment process goes fine, but considering the deployment on the staging account to test the deployment process (production server) the command who runs the deployment doesn't work. On the server, I pulled the changes and even running `composer global require laravel/envoy` and `composer global update` but no results.

Firstly I was having this error "-bash: envoy: command not found" so searching on google I added some tweaks I added the /.composer/vendor/bin directory (wasn't exist but in my vagrant homestead does exist) besides I added the file ~/.composer/vendor/bin/envoy and I bash it on my ~/.bash_profile adding export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin" and well I am not having them anymore the error mentioned "-bash: envoy: command not found" but now instead of when I hit envoy run deploy the response is nothing!.

Answer (score 1):

i found the way to troubleshoot this issue, keep in mind than Envoy runs outside laravel project folder i mean one folder back ../, Envoy is installed on ~/.composer folder so what was happening is at my production server outside the laravel folder was running on php 5.6 instead 7.x that's why the composer install `composer global require laravel/envoy` didn't go through that all so after i upgraded the php version in the general server the Envoy works. This ticket is closed